# Reading data from file without manually inputing the length it the array

Tags: java

Please I will like to adjust this code that reads integers from a file.
I will like the code to detect the number (n) of the dataset instead of having to put in figures manually as done below (4000 )

double[] tall = new double[4000];

```
public class Extracto {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File fil = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\kaycee2.csv");
        FileReader inputFil = new FileReader(fil);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inputFil);
        double[] tall = new double[4000];
        String s = in.readLine();
        int i = 0;
        while (s != null) {
            // Skip empty lines.
            s = s.trim();
            if (s.length() == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            tall[i] = Double.parseDouble(s); // This is line 19.
            //  System.out.println(tall[i]);
            s = in.readLine();
            i++;

        }
```

I am expecting the adjusted code to obtain the data length without manually putting it in like in as shown in the code below for the 4000 length.

double[] tall = new double[4000];

Comment: Use a [list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead of an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Thomas mentioned, use a list, instead of an array.

```
    File fil = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\kaycee2.csv");
    FileReader inputFil = new FileReader(fil);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inputFil);
    ArrayList<Double> tall = new ArrayList<>();
    while(in.ready()){ 
        String s = in.readLine().trim();
        if(!s.isEmpty()){
           tall.add(Double.parseDouble(s);
        } 
    }
```

your codes can be further compacted if you use a list.
also do add a try-catch in the event when the String read is not a number.

Comment: Thank you very much @ Angel